# flutter : How to use shared preferences to keep user logged in

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to keep the user logged in after the user successfully logsin in flutter. I am using a REST API to retrieve the user name and password of the user. But I want to save those details so that the user can stay logged in. My current situation is i can successfully log the user in but when i restart the app i have to login again so i need to save the details of the user in a shared preference so that the user can stay logged for the entire session until logout.But i am unable to do that so please help me with it. Thanks in advance

Login.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(3, 9, 23, 1),
      body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 100,
            right: 30,
            left: 30,
          ),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FadeAnimation(
                      1.2,
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(70.0),
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                    'assets/images/trakinglogo.png'))),
                      )),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 30,
                  ),
                  FadeAnimation(
                      1.5,
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            color: Colors.white),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border(
                                      bottom:
                                          BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300]))),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                controller: _emailController,
                                onFieldSubmitted: (_) =>
                                    FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
                                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                                    return 'Email is required';
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.8)),
                                    hintText: "Votre adresse mail"),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                controller: _passwordController,
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                                    return 'Password is required';
                                  }
                                  return null;
                                },
                                obscureText: _isHidden,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(.8)),
                                  hintText: "Mot de passe",
                                  suffix: InkWell(
                                      onTap: _togglePasswordView,
                                      child: Icon(
                                        _isHidden
                                            ? (CommunityMaterialIcons
                                                .eye_outline)
                                            : (CommunityMaterialIcons.eye_off),
                                        color: Color(0xFF939394),
                      
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 40,
                  ),
                  FadeAnimation(
                      1.8,
                      Center(
                          child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                child: RaisedButton(
                                  textColor: Colors.white,
                                  color: kPrimaryColor,
                                  child: Text("Se connecter"),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                      showDialog(
                                          context: context,
                                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                            return Center(
                                              child:
                                                  CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                            );
                                          });
                                      await loginUser();
                                    }
                                    /*  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => MyWidget()),
                                    );*/
                                    // Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'Mywidget');
                                  },
                                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                width: 250,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              AlreadyHaveAnAccountCheck(
                                press: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) {
                                        return SignUp();

 void loginUser() async {
    // if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    String email = _emailController.text;
    String password = _passwordController.text;

    authentication.login(email, password).then((user) {
      if (user != null)
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyWidget()));
    }).catchError((error) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(error.toString())));
    });

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

and this is login function :

```dart
Future<User> login(String email, String password) async {
  await checkInternet();

  Map<String, String> headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  };
  Map<String, String> body = {'email': email, 'password': password};

  var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(ApiUtil.AUTH_LOGIN),
      headers: headers, body: jsonEncode(body));
  switch (response.statusCode) {
    case 200:
      var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      var data = body['user'];
      User user = User.fromJson(data);
      Track track = Track.fromJson(body);

      if (body['code'] == 0) {
        SharedPreferences localStorage =
        await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        localStorage.setInt('id', body['user']['id']);
        localStorage.setString('adress', body['user']['adress']);
        localStorage.setString('phone', body['user']['phone']);
        localStorage.setString('access_token', body['access_token']);
        localStorage.setString('user', json.encode(body['user']));
        String user = localStorage.getString('user');

      }
      return user;
    case 500:
      throw ('Erreur serveur');
      break;

    case 400:
      throw LoginFailed();
    default:
      throw ('connection timeout');
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: DO NOT save your users credentials in shared preferences. This is a must not do. Shared preferences is very easily accessible and not encrypted.

Comment: @csguy Yes it's right, But currently he is not saving any confidential information in ```SharedPreference```.

Comment: Same of the answers do save the password, thats why I commented also his wording makes it seem like he is storing the password not the token.

Answer (score 1):

Make a class `AppSharedPreference` and in that class make these methods:

**`User`** is your `modal` class.

**Save User:**

```
static saveUser(String key, User value) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //We cannot save custom objects.
    //So json.encode is used to convert User Object to Json a string.
    prefs.setString(key, json.encode(value));
  }
```

**Get User:**

```
static readUser(String key) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    //json.decode to convert json string back to Json Object
    return json.decode(prefs.getString(key));
  }
```

Make Sure your modal `User` class contains toJson method:

```
Map<String, String> toJson() => {
        'id': Id,
        'address': address,
        'phone': phone,
        // rest of your attributes...
      };
```

To call the `saveUser` method:

```
await AppSharedPreference.saveUser('your_key', user);
```

To call the `readUser` method:
(make sure your modal `User` class contains fromJson method)

```
User user = User.fromJson(await AppSharedPreference.readUser('your_key'));
```

And after that you can check whether the `user` is `null` or not. If it is `null` it means there is no data and the `user` is not logged-in.

In case if you want to `logout` user you can create a method to remove the user from `SharedPreference`:

**Remove User:**

```
static removeUser(String key) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.remove(key);
}
```

To call `removeUser` method:

```
await AppSharedPreference.removeUser('your_key');
```

Comment: I created a class as you said . user model contains tojson and fromjson method. but i can't call readUser and saveUser correctly in my code . can you help me ? @Ahmad Rehan

Comment: @lucky I have added the lines how to ```readUser```, ```saveUser``` and ```removeUser```.

Comment: i changed       User user = User.fromJson(data);
by User user = User.fromJson(await AppSharedPreference.readUser('access_token'));
 in my code .  i have error when i try to log : the getter length was called on null. reciever : null

Comment: sorry i confused . i put  User user = User.fromJson(await AppSharedPreference.readUser(data)); ==>  Map <string, dynamic> is not subtype of type string

Comment: @lucky Do the same as you already doing like:

 ```var body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      var data = body['user'];
      User user = User.fromJson(data);```
And then save the user to Shared Preference:
```await AppSharedPreference.saveUser('your_key', user);```
And also before pushing the login screen get the user from SharedPreference if it is not ```null``` this means the user already logged-in and no need to push Login Screen, you can push Home Screen.
And if it is ```null``` then push the Login Screen to ask the user to Login first.

Comment: can go to chat please ? @Ahmad Rehan

Comment: I logged with success but i can't get the user from SharedPreference correctly @Ahmad Rehan

Comment: @lucky Please edit your question code and add the new code for better understanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233093/discussion-between-lucky-and-ahmad-rehan).

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if there is data in the sharedPreference at the starting of the app and then redirect users based on that. An example would be implementing this in splashscreen

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'home_page.dart';
import 'login_page.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String splashRoute = '/';

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  void timeToShowSplashScreenOnScreen() async {
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () async {
      if (!mounted) return;
      SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      bool isLoggedIn = _prefs.getBool("loggedIn");
      if (isLoggedIn != null && isLoggedIn) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(HomePage.homePageRoute, (route) => false);
      } else {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(LoginPage.loginRoute, (route) => false);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timeToShowSplashScreenOnScreen();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: _width,
        height: _height,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            // Your UI for splash screen
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This example uses boolean values stored in prefs but you can do similar things with strings too.